# two or more render/redirect in the same method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I often have method like this one with two or more render to do due to catching the error for example.
I currently do something like this:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  if params[:user][:camera_type].present? && params[:user][:lens_type].present? && params[:user][:photo].present?
    r = Photo.instance.Upload(camera_type: @user.id,
                              album: @user.default_album,
                              photo: params[:user][:photo],
                              lens_type: params[:user][:lens_type],
                              camera_type: params[:user][:camera_type])
    @user.camera_type = params[:user][:camera_type]
    @user.lens_type = params[:user][:lens_type]
    @user.photo = params[:user][:photo]
    @user.save!
    render action: 'edit'
    return
  end
rescue Photo => e
  redirect_to photo_path, :flash => { :alert => t(:text_photo_edit_failed) }
end
```

But may be there is a better way to do it ?

Comment: can you fix the indentation?

Comment: @tokland Fixed it - was thinking about doing that earlier, but wasn't even sure I knew how. A lot going on there, none of it clear :/

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- Keep your controllers lean, this is too much code for an action.
- The photo upload should be done as a part of the object's save chain (after validation), so create a `before_save` callback in the `User` model that returns `false` if the upload fails.
- You set `r` (cryptic name) but don't use it anywhere? does the upload raise an exception on error?

At the end the controller should look extremely simple, something like:

```
def update
  @user = current_user

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    render action: 'edit'
  else
    redirect_to photo_path, flash: {alert: t(:text_photo_edit_failed)}
  end
end
```

Any additional logic should be in `User`. Models are easy to test in isolation, controllers on the other hand have a lot of state to worry about.

Comment: Agreed, most of this should be moved into models. There's also some weirdly suspect bits of code here suggesting you need to work out some kinks in your model layer, like `Upload` as a method name, or `camera_type: @user.id`. What is a user's ID doing there, being called a "camera_type"? You also generally shouldn't have to check for specific parameters to be present, rather you prevent models from being moved into an invalid state *at the model level*, via validations.

Comment: @meagar `camera_type: @user.id` is the typo mistake. my bad.